# JavaScript style.maxHeight no working in android 5.0.2

Tags: javascript, android

I have the following code to adjust and image to the screen, there might be margins. img.style.maxHeight, in percentege, works fine in android 4 (all versions) but not on android 5.0.2. If I use px (for instance 95px) it works:

```
<div id="firstPostPicContainer" class="postPic"></div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = 'resizedPicture.php?url={imgData}_1&for=posts&w=1500';
    img.style.maxWidth  = "100%";
    img.style.maxHeight = "100%";
    img.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("firstPostPicContainer").appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
```

Basically the above code doesn't adjust the image height if it is in % but it does using px

Comment: Please define "no working". What size you get instead of the expected?

Comment: It doesn't adjust the size. I've tried with lowered percentage, for instance 95%, and the image is not adjusted. If I try with px, lets say 95px, the image is adjusted

Comment: I asked specifically, what size you get? If the original image is smaller than the wrapping div, setting `max...` won't resize the image, you'd need `min...`.

Comment: the original image is larger

Comment: And now when you're adding it to the, it overflows? Or is the wrapper div resized?

Comment: I've have to slide up. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Now I've added `style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%"` to the div. It's not working neither